# Paths from one corner to another

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

Given a square grid of size $n \times n$, how many paths are there from one corner to a diagonally opposite corner?

I searched OEIS but was only able to find [this](https://oeis.org/A007764). The numbers there reflect only non-intersecting paths. I'm interested in all paths.

Thoughts?

**EDIT**

A path may not traverse any edge it has previously traversed.

Only rook moves allowed.

Comment: Is a path allowed to retrace itself?  If so, there are infinitely many paths.  If not, then I think you need to specify more clearly what kinds of paths are allowed.

Comment: @mweiss: It is not. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: It is a simple linear relation for each node. Just set up a linear equation system and solve with linear least squares.

Comment: What steps are allowed ? & are there any restrictions like not self intersecting ?

Comment: @mathreadler: Sounds simple. If you can do it, please do so in an answer.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit: The link I gave gives all non-intersecting paths. I'm interested in all paths, intersecting or not.

Comment: If intersecting is allowed you can build loops and there will easily be infinite number of paths. I think you need to specify the question more carefully. It is too late for me now. Maybe I will have time some evening or weekend.

Comment: @mathreadler: Please see my earlier edit. Paths may not traverse any edge they have previously traversed.

Comment: The question is still not specific enough. You also need to specify which nodes are connected to each other with edges and which are not. Can we go like rooks or bishops or queens or horses or..?

Comment: @mathreadler: Sorry. I just a assumed that a square grid would imply rook moves only.

Comment: How did you search OEIS? By text search, or by computing the first few terms and searching for them? If you haven't done the latter, you should try it; it shouldn't be too much work to get up to $n=3$, and that might narrow the search down enough to look through all the entries found.

Comment: By "rook moves" do you mean that a path can go from $(1,1)$ to $(3,1)$ directly, and this is different from going from $(1,1)$ to $(2,1)$ to $(3,1)$?

Comment: @Joriki: It was a text search only. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @Misha: The two paths you mention would be considered the same as they pass through the same grid points.

Comment: @Joriki: Using your suggestion I found [the sequence](https://oeis.org/A013990) in OEIS. Thanks.