# Finding the number of non-decreasing traversals of a grid

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to find the number of non-decreasing traversals of an $n$ by $m$ grid ($n$ rows, $m$ columns) with $n<m$ from the bottom-left corner square to the top-right corner square. Here is an example for $m=8, n=4$:
[image]

Equivalently, I'm trying to find the number of non-decreasing (i.e. $k_1 = 1 \leq k_2 \leq ... \leq k_m = n$) sequences where $k_i \leq n$ and every number in $\{1, ..., n\}$ appears at least once.

This initially looked like a stars-and-bars problem with $\sum k_i = M$ but this construction doesn't quite work (I couldn't find a way to encode the "every number in $\{1, ..., n\}$ appears at least once" criterion).

Comment: Duplicate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825417/paths-from-one-corner-to-another

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The link you sent considers rook moves and an $n$x$n$ grid, neither of which are the case here (the sequence interpretation makes this more clear).

Comment: Equivalent problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966189/combinatorics-6-digits-decreasing-code/3966196#3966196

Comment: Also -- you can't always have $k_1,\dots, k_m$ covering every number $1,\dots,n$. What if $m<n$? A general method for this problem shouldn't need you to turn your head sideways.

Comment: The non-decreasing traversals of the grid problem *is* identical to the rook move problem as stated (where you cannot travers a line twice).  Check.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork As I understand it, this problem only allows for one-step bishop or one-step horizontal rook moves. I have added a picture for $m=8, n=4$ to make this more clear.

Comment: @jlammy Correct, this only makes sense for $m \leq n$; I've edited the question to reflect this

Comment: I'm confused about the diagonal moves. The nondecreasing sequence: $(a1,b1,b2,c2,\dots,h4)$ is different from $(a1,b1,c1,c2,\dots,h4)$, but both count for the same diagonal move. I assume they are supposed to be different?

Comment: The only allowed moves are diagonal move and right move? Then, you always have exactly $m-1$ diagonal moves (otherwise you will either not reach the top layer or move beyond it) and the rest of $n-1$ moves (you don't move anywhere from the last square) are right moves, therefore the answer is $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Replace each diagonal step by an up-step, and you get a path by rook moves from $\langle 1,1\rangle$ to $\langle n-m+1,m\rangle$. This path consists of $m-1$ up-steps and $n-m$ right-steps, for a total of $n-1$ steps. The steps can be taken in any order, and the path is completely determined when we know which steps are up-steps, so there are $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ possible paths. On your $8\times 4$ board, for instance, there are $\binom73=35$ such paths.

Note that the transformation from one of your paths to a rook path is reversible simply by replacing each up-step by a diagonal step, so it really does define a bijection between your paths on an $n\times m$ board on and rook paths on an $(n-m+1)\times m$ board.